# how to retrive image from Mysql database using spring?

Tags: mysql, spring, file-upload, blob

I insert image to Mysql database , image will be stored .

```
File file = new File("G:/photos/New Folder (2)/www.geocities.com_cliknenjoy_lakshmimittal.jpg");

byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

try {

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    fileInputStream.read(bFile);
    fileInputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();

}
inpatient.setImagefile(bFile);
```

i use blob data type in mysql.

```
private byte[] imagefile;

public byte[] getImagefile() {      
    return imagefile;   
}   

public void setImagefile(byte[] imagefile) { 
    this.imagefile = imagefile;     
}
```

now i can't open image file from mysqldatabase , how can i open this one?

Comment: you sey that you are using Blob, but in your example I can see byte[] ?

Comment: You haven't shown how you store it or how you read it.

Comment: ya i stored byte[] , but i it will stored blob data type using in mysql, i can open and see the image from mysql . but i need open via coding , image disply from database. how i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JPA annotations, you could annotate your property as `@Lob`

```
@Lob
private byte[] imagefile;
```

And maybe also with `@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` to avoid data overhead.

Stefano

-- Edit

Once you have persisted the image binary content as a byte[], you have two ways to show the image: write a new servlet or a new controller. The first adds unnecessary complexity so I generally use the second approach.

First you must choose the path on which the controller will respond; suppose `"/dbresources/images/{id}"`

The the controller will be something like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/dbresources/images")
public class PictureImageController {

    @Autowired
    private PictureService pictureService; // a service to retrieve pictures fomr DB

    // getters and setters

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}")
public void writePicture(@PathVariable("id") String id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        try{
            Picture img = pictureService.findById(id);
            response.setContent(picture.getImagefile());
            response.setContentLength(picture.getImagefile().length);

            //additionally, you should add the mime-type and the last
            //change date (to allow the browsers to use the cache) if these info are available

            response.getOutputStream().write(picture.getImagefile());
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404. Add specific catch for specific errors
        }
}
```

Then in your jsp(x) you'll need to write

```
<img src="/dbresources/images/[the id of the image to show]" />
```

The controller will intercept this request and will process it writing in the output stream the binary content of the image.

Hope this is clear enough. And don't trust code correctness because I wrote it on the fly.

Stefano

Comment: **i use this annotations but still i am getting that image will be displayed [B@100271a like this , how can i open file ?""

Comment: I can't understand what you are searching for. Do you mean, "how can I display the actual image in the GUI of the application starting from its binary representation?". If so, is it a web application?

Comment: **ya of course , i want change  conversion , if anything possible to display gui mode in webapplication?**